# How to return specific key from an Object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Object which looks like this:

```
   servers = {"ErrorCode":"0",
              "NodeList":[{
                          "HostName":"d4",
                          "FQDN":"s3",
                          "Role":"GHI",
                          "productTypeId":"1",
                          "DNSResolved":"true"
                          }, 
                          {
                          "HostName":"a5",
                          "FQDN":"s2",
                          "Role":"ABC",
                           "productTypeId":"2",
                           "DNSResolved":"true"
                           },
                          {
                         "HostName":"a1",
                         "FQDN":"c1",
                         "Role":"DEF",
                         "productTypeId":"1",
                         "DNSResolved":"true"
                        }]
                     }
```

I want the `NodeList` key and out of which I want to extract the `HostName`. I have tried the following code to extract the `NodeList` and then to map over it. But the `NodeList` key is not even getting printed.

```
console.log('servers', Object.keys(servers).find(node => {
      return servers[node] === 'NodeList';
    }))
```

It returns `undefined`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what “key” means…. In this case, you don’t “return a specific key” - you want _the value_ for a specific key from _another_ object at a specific index in an array. And in this case there are three separate array elements and you haven’t said which one you want. So how is `map` going to help you?

Comment: `servers.NodeList.map(x => x.HostName)` gives `[ 'd4', 'a5', 'a1' ]`, is that what you want?

Comment: @LionelRowe exactly. I tried that , but I get an error on NodelIst saying `Property NodeList doesnot exist on type string`. Actually I am trying to get this value fromsessionStorage like ` const servers = window.sessionStorage.getItem('hostList');` and then `console.log('servers', Object.keys(servers).find(node => {
      return servers[node] === 'NodeList';
    }))`. Why am I gettin gthis error, any idea?

Comment: you need to use JSON,.parse

Comment: @pranami `sessionStorage` can only store strings. If you want to store complex data in it, you need to `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Comment: It worked . Thanks @LionelRowe , Vimal Patel :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
servers["NodeList"].map(item=>item.HostName)
```